# Fixed top bar + 100% height fixed sidebar?

Tags: css, overflow, css-position, fixed, sidebar

I'm wondering how to make a proper layout for fixed navbar markup with sidebard. What I'm trying to archieve:

1. Fixed navbar
2. Fixed right column (sidebar)
3. Fluid left coumn (content)

**Sidebar**

Sidebar height is always 100% of widnow height except navbar. When sidebar content height is more than sidebar height, I need to scoll it's content. In the endpoint of sidebar scroll (then sidebard is scrolled to it's bottom) I wish main content to start scrolling and vice versa.

Here'is the layout:

[image]

What I've got now: http://jsfiddle.net/MNN28/1/

```
html,
body {
  width  : 100%;
  height : 100%;
}
body {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}
.container {
  width    : 100%;
  height   : 100%;
  overflow : hidden;
}
.navbar {
  position : fixed;
  height   : 45px;
  width    : 100%;
  z-index  : 9;
}
.main {
  position : absolute;
  top      : 45px;
  width    : 100%;
  height   : 100%;
  overflow : hidden;
}
.main-container {
  overflow : scroll;
  width    : 1200px;
  margin   : 0px auto;
}
.main-container-center {
  width    : 600px;
  height   : 100%;
  float    : left;
  overflow : scroll;
}
.main-container-right {
  position    : fixed;
  width       : 600px; 
  height      : 100%;
  float       : left;
  margin-left : 975px;
  overflow    : scroll;
}
```

There are two main issues in this markup:

1. I dont want to have separate scrollbar for content column, is should be native page scrolling.
2. Some text both in content and in sidebar area is cutted even after scroll (I suppose it's because of navbar height).

How to correct my markup to make it work as expected? Thanks.

Comment: So if I understand right you want a sticky sidebar that stays at place when scrolling the 'blue' content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you descriped. You can scroll your `<body>` content like alwas and have a max-height fixed sidebar.

http://jsfiddle.net/MNN28/2/

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  height: 45px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #262626;
  z-index: 9;
}
.main {
  position: relative;
  top: 45px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom:0;
}
.main-container {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}
.main-container-center {
  width: 600px;
  top: 45px;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}
.main-container-right {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #d9d9d9;
  width: 600px;
  bottom:0;
  margin-left: 600px;
  overflow: auto;
  top: 45px;
}
```

Comment: Seems to be working as expected! And is there a way to make columns crop content not by navbar bottom line, but with 10px margin from navbar while scrolling? Anyway, I'll mark your question as accepted, thank you!

Comment: yes, just play widht the `top: 45px` value. 45px = navbar height. http://jsfiddle.net/MNN28/3/

Comment: noticed a stange bug — when window width is <1200px, I get a horizontal scroll. The less page width, the more the gap between columns. I've tried to play with overflows, but no luck. Seems that fixed container width is the reason. Any ideas how to fix it? Thank you!